# Process A to write data member of Process B directly

Tags: c++, boost, software-distribution

I have a c++ programme. There are two processes which run in two terminal.

Take a easy example, *Process A* is a sender and *Process B* is a receiver.

They are connected through TCP/IP protocol by Boost.

*Process A* can send Data and *process B* will receive and then write them in an `int` array. Like `int mem[32]`

The problem I met is that it is too slow. Is there a way to access "`mem[32]` of *Process B*" directly from *Process A* so that TCP/IP can be bypassed? Like passing some pointers?(As the two process are located in the same computer, there shall be some ways to access common memory places?)

So is that possible? What shall I look into? (memory management?)

Thanks

Comment: [Shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory). However, there are [many other IPC methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Main_IPC_methods).

Comment: I *was* answering your question!! Why did you delete it? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21183321/6309 Please undelete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) library to create a shared memory that can be accessed by multiple processors.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll look into the Shared Memory

Answer (score 0):

Memory of a process could not commonly be accessed by another process.

You could share pointer between threads, but not between processes.

Have you try to use sockets, it is commonly used to communicate between processes, and also could be used between separated computers ?

Comment: socket is too slow in my situation. I guess I will look into the Shared Memory